# can relative risk be calculated from a 2 by 3 table

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, contingency-tables, multinomial-logit

I have a question regarding relative risk.

I have a table like this:

```
           outcome   
           -1   0  1
group 1    25  52  6    
group 2    21  69  9
```

So the outcome is some category of changes (i.e they are they category of -1,0,and 1). And the factor is group.

I ran a multinomial logistic regression (using the code from here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) 
with the reference level being "-1".

I got the relative risk from the program in R to be:

case 1: 
1.5796 (the relative risk of having a change of "0" vs change of "-1" for being in group 2 compared to being in group 1) and

case 2:
1.7854 (the relative risk of having a change of "1" vs change of "-1" for being in group 2 compared to being in group 1).

My question is, is the value of 1.5796, and 1.7854 correct based on the table above?

Because I thought relative risk can be calculated from the table (at least I know I can do that when I have a 2 by 2 table).

So in this case, can I calculate the relative risk to be (69/(21+69+9)) / (52/(25+52+6)) for the first case,

and (9/(21+69+9)) /  (6/(25+52+6))   for the second case by hand-calculation like this? because it seems these two values are quite different from the values given by the multinomial logistic regression.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate by hand you only need to take account of the values in the specific 2 by 2 table you are working with not the whole table. It seems you have an ordered outcome and it might be better to investigate ordinal regression models although that would depend on your underlying scientific question.

The term relative risk is often used to include both odds ratios, which is what logistic regression gives you, and risk ratios, which I think is what you are trying to compute by hand.

Comment: Hi Professor, thanks for your answer. I guess I was hand-calculating an odd ratio like what you said for both case 1 and case 2 in above. But if I calculate for case 1 using the following: denoted K = (69/(21+69)) / (52/(25+52)) , (i.e. both denominator without the number in the third column of the table to make the sum), does it mean this number gives relative risk of "0" vs "1" for being in group 2 compared to being in group 1?  but K = 1.135 as a relative risk which is still quite different from what the program gives.